# How to set a time for progressive dialog?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to set a time (for example 5 seconds) for ProgressDialog in my android app. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean? Set time for what?

Comment: At some point in my app when a certain activity starts I show a progress dialog bar which stops only when I press the back button.Next I wanna set up a time for my progress dialog to appear for only that set interval time.Do u get it?

Comment: Now I get it. duonghv has answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use handler for this.Firstly start show dialog and at this time sendMessageForDelay(event_id,5*1000) and at handleMessage you check dialog is showing or not.If showing you dismiss it.Goodluck :)